# Jquery get multiple checked values from checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

My form have following checkbox and I want to tick the option to show an alert with checked values, but there is nothing happen to show up the alert when I ticked it:

```
<form id="booking_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="bType[]" id="bType" value="A,200">&nbsp;Type A - USD200<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bType[]" id="bType" value="B,150">&nbsp;Type B - USD150<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bType[]" id="bType" value="C,100">&nbsp;Type C - USD100<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bType[]" id="bType" value="D,50">&nbsp;Type D - USD50<br>

</form>
```

and I have JQ script:

```
<script>
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each ( function() {
    alert ( $(this).val() );
});
</script>
```

please advise, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with Javascript?

Comment: you need to bind the change on checkbox

Comment: id of your checkboxes MUST BE UNIQUE

Answer (score 5):

You have to add an event handler that initiates the code. Now it runs when the page is loading.

For instance, you can let a button click handle it:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        alert( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tMRvL/

Comment: the original question ask to bind the event to the click, not to a button

Answer (score 2):

That should works

```
  $("input[type=checkbox]").change( function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       alert( $(this).val() );
    }
  });
```

[Demo on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/Y9KgQ/), [other demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ocadug/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $("[type=checkbox]:checked").each ( function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Worked for me :)

Comment: don't forget to add some description/details while giving answer